# Why "package natbib warning: there where undefined citations. and result is "?"

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@misc {dg,
  author = {{Detroit Gazette}},
  note   = {1817--1830. Microfilm edition, Detroit Gazette Collection, 
            c.~123, XYZ University Library, University Town, State},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % choose a bibliography style that suits your needs

\begin{document}
\dots{} as the Ohio Canal fund \citep[Dec~11 1827,p.~2, c.~5]{dg}\dots
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

the result is:

> . . . as the Ohio Canal fund (?, Dec 11 1827,p. 2, c. 5). . .

Comment: [Undefined citation in Bibtex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241399)

Comment: What were you expecting instead?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I guess the real citation instead of the question mark -> [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Yes, it definitely is as it compiles without flaws. I am waiting for confirmation of the OP.

Comment: Are there any news here?